# Dynamic progress bar for Firebase Storage Upload

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

My problem is that I can't get `firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot.bytesTransferred` directly from `firebasePutString`, but need to use the `.on("state_changed")` method, but this method is called only every few seconds (every 256Kb), so the progress bar isn't really dynamic. I can't figure out how to call it directly from my `firebasePutString` object. Any ideas??

```
let firebasePutString = firebase.storage().ref(`/${UID}/${fileName}`).putString(data, 'data_url');
firebasePutString.on('state_changed',
function progress(snapshot) {
  console.log("snapshot: " + snapshot);
  this.percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log("percentage2: " + this.percentage);
},
function error(err) {},
function complete() {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code of my solution, not the most elegant, but works fairly well:

let interim: number = 0;
    let firebaseRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/path/`);
    let firebasePutString = firebaseRef.putString(data, 'data_url');

```
let mySubscription = Observable.interval(50).subscribe( _ => {
    if (firebasePutString.snapshot.totalBytes === firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred) {
      interim = firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred;
      this.percentage = parseInt(((interim / firebasePutString.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100).toFixed(0));
      mySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    else if (interim === 0 && firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred === 0 && this.percentage < 100) {
      this.percentage = this.percentage + 1;
    }
    else if (interim === 0 && firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred !== 0) {
      interim = firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred;
      (this.percentage < parseInt(((interim / firebasePutString.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100).toFixed(0))) ? this.percentage = parseInt(((interim / firebasePutString.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100).toFixed(0)) : (this.percentage = this.percentage);
    }
    else if(interim === firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred && this.percentage < 100) {
      this.percentage = this.percentage + 1;
    }
    else {
      interim = firebasePutString.snapshot.bytesTransferred;
      (this.percentage < parseInt(((interim / firebasePutString.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100).toFixed(0))) ? this.percentage = parseInt(((interim / firebasePutString.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100).toFixed(0)) : (this.percentage = this.percentage);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Storage SDK only reports progress in 256KB increments. Unless you come up with some low-level way of measuring progress on your own, this is as good as it's going to get.

Comment: I'm solved this in another way. Taking the length of the video (or it's size), I'm smoothing out the jumps between each snapshot request, and it comes out almost perfectly smooth!

Comment: That sounds like a cool solution. Is there any chance you could show the minimal code for that in a separate answer? It might be useful to others looking to do the same.

Comment: Sure, posted below!